# How to refresh data in Textfield in JFrame with your specified data without creating another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having issues with updating the data in JTextField in JFrame with new data. When even I want new data in JTestField, it just creates another JFrame and writes the data in that JTextField.

What i want is to update the JTextField in the current JFrame without creating other JFrames when I want new data in JTextField. 
Is this possible to do ? Please help

Comment: How are you doing it? Please share the code because it's not clear.

Comment: the code is long, and there is many classes, is it possible i can e-mail you ?

Comment: Do you know what is relevant code for this issue? Can you create a sample code first then post it here.

Comment: Just make a pastebin online, and provide the link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fzQ8aFzt  http://pastebin.com/0S2iQPPb   http://pastebin.com/UQ7nff0n   Those are the 3 main files of code for the problem that i'm having

Comment: I'm having issues in Search.java in method Search_Customer_Surname_in_Database()

Comment: Can any one help me please

Comment: *"Those are the 3 main files"*  Don't expect people to either follow links or piece together bits of code to get something compilable.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

You would get better answers if you would show your code. try:

```
JTextField myField;
//code here...
myField.setText("text")
```